# How to make Splash Screen for custom theme mode in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have implemented custom theme mode rather than picking system theme, now i am unable to implement splash screen for my custom theme.
I want to check the value in my preferences and then apply the changes to splash api.

```
@Inject
lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
        if (splashViewModel.isDarkMode.value){
        splashScreen.setSplashScreenTheme(R.style.SplashScreenTheme) }
        splashViewModel.isLoading.value
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = viewModel()
        val isDarkTheme =  userViewModel.getSavedTheme().collectAsState(initial = true).value
        userViewModel.observeLifecycleEvents(LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle)
        SharpWalletTheme(darkTheme = isDarkTheme) {
            val startDestination by splashViewModel.startDestination
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            val isUserAuth by userViewModel.isUserAuth
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                RootNavigationGraph(
                    navHostController = navController,
                    startDestination = startDestination,
                    userViewModel = userViewModel,
                    toAuthUser = isUserAuth,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

-update 1
my splashViewModel is as follows -

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: UserRepository
```

) : ViewModel() {

```
private val _isLoading: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(true)
val isLoading: State<Boolean> = _isLoading

private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(Graph.ON_BOARDING)
val startDestination: State<String> = _startDestination

private val _isDarkMode: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(true)
val isDarkMode: State<Boolean> = _isDarkMode

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.readDarkModePreference().collect {
            _isDarkMode.value = it
        }
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.readOnBoardingState().collect { completed ->
            if (completed) {
                _startDestination.value = Graph.MAIN
            } else {
                _startDestination.value = Graph.ON_BOARDING
            }
            delay(500)
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

}

- update 2
  if i do  something like below Then woolah it works But when i change the theme from the app it doesn't show correctly in first time although from second it show correct.

  ```
        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (splashViewModel.isDarkMode.value) {
                splashScreen.setSplashScreenTheme(R.style.Theme_App_StartingDarkMode)
            } else {
                splashScreen.setSplashScreenTheme(R.style.Theme_App_StartingLightMode)
            }
        }
        Timber.d("splash value is ${splashViewModel.isDarkMode.value}")
        splashViewModel.isLoading.value
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  ```

[image: see example here]

Comment: I think it's not possible at this moment. bcoz, it's run before your nav graph initializes. Whatsapp also not able to manage this.

Comment: @HanifShaikh but in android default phon and message application is doing this. I dont know how

Comment: You should put separately created ```themes.xml``` file in ```values-nigh``` folder. So It can take the Theme change automatically

Comment: yes i was working like that but now i want to change the theme according the preference data store value that isDarkTheme.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can change the splash screen after it's already shown, what you can do is to quickly transition from the default splash screen to a secondary "splash screen" that matches the correct theme.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

    splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenProvider ->
        val fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splashScreenProvider.view, View.ALPHA, 0f)
        fadeOut.duration = 500L // Or your desired duration
        fadeOut.doOnEnd { splashScreenProvider.remove() }
        fadeOut.start()
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    splashViewModel.isDarkMode.observe(this, { isDarkMode ->
        if (isDarkMode) {
            // Here, instead of changing the splash screen (which you can't after it's shown),
            // You might transition to another screen or adjust the current theme, to mimic the splash screen 
            // adapting to the dark mode. 
        }
    })

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

upadte code:

```
<!-- Light Splash Theme -->
<style name="LightSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_light_icon</item>
    <!-- Other attributes for the light splash screen... -->
</style>

<!-- Dark Splash Theme -->
<style name="DarkSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_dark_icon</item>
    <!-- Other attributes for the dark splash screen... -->
</style>
```

code

```
@Inject
lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Before super.onCreate, decide which theme to use for the splash screen.
    if (splashViewModel.isDarkMode.value) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkSplashScreenTheme)
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.LightSplashScreenTheme)
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
        splashViewModel.isLoading.value
    }
    
    splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenViewProvider ->
        val fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            splashScreenViewProvider.view,
            View.ALPHA,
            1f,
            0f
        )
        fadeOut.duration = 500L
        fadeOut.doOnEnd {
            splashScreenViewProvider.remove()
        }
        fadeOut.start()
    }
    
    setContent {
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = viewModel()
        val isDarkTheme = userViewModel.getSavedTheme().collectAsState(initial = true).value
        userViewModel.observeLifecycleEvents(LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle)
        
        SharpWalletTheme(darkTheme = isDarkTheme) {
            val startDestination by splashViewModel.startDestination
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            val isUserAuth by userViewModel.isUserAuth
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                RootNavigationGraph(
                    navHostController = navController,
                    startDestination = startDestination,
                    userViewModel = userViewModel,
                    toAuthUser = isUserAuth,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will it show a splash screen for 400 milliseconds? then out screen(as another splash)

Comment: the code set for 500, you set it for your needs

Comment: I am already running a delay of 500 in splashViewmodel. I have updated the question can you suggest the solution now

Comment: your model is ok (you should not use State in model use StateFlow) you need to create two screens and set them before the onCreate, look at the updated answer

Comment: if I do a check before super.onCreate than it throws error because of the splash ViewModel initialization : please watch update 2